# One Particle System is working, the other comes out the underside of the Emitter object?

Tags: mesh, normals

I’m making a flower. I have the petals weight-painted around the bulb which are working just fine. I made a second vertex group but the smaller central petals are coming out of the bottom of the mesh. Is it not a Normals problem? How could that be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out—I needed to go to my source object, rotate it 180 degrees along the Z axis, and apply (Ctrl+A) the Rotation.